# WCF .config file - something is plainly wrong

Tags: wcf, app-config

Folks,
I've got something wrong with this .config for my WCF.  When I send data to it more than 8192 bytes (the default) it fails, telling me my "maxStringContentLength" is only 8192.  I *think* I have it set here to 10,000,000.

Any clues?

```
<system.serviceModel>
 <bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="wsHttpBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="50000000" maxBufferPoolSize="50000000" messageEncoding="Mtom">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="200" maxStringContentLength="10000000" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="10000000" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>     
  <service name="PsychCoverage.WcfMT.Admin">
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="PsychCoverage.Common.IAdmin">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/WcfMT/Admin/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior >
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True"  />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Yes - you have set it **on the server/service side** - what about your client calling this service??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do have it set, but you're not referencing it in the endpoint element, so .NET is using the default for wsHttpBinding (8192).  Add the config you specified using the bindingConfiguration attribute of the endpoint element:

```
<endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsHttpBinding" contract="PsychCoverage.Common.IAdmin">
```

Also, I'd recommend using a different name than wsHttpBinding to prevent confusion.

Comment: So if I changed my <binding/> to this...
          <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="wcfMyProject" maxReceivedMessageSize="50000000" maxBufferPoolSize="50000000" messageEncoding="Mtom">

...and changed my <endpoint/> to this...

    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding"  bindingConfiguration="wcfMyProject" contract="PsychCoverage.Common.IAdmin">

...then my endpoint should use my binding configuration?

Comment: Yes, your endpoint should set bindingConfiguration="wcfMyProject".  Comments don't support code formatting, by the way - only questions and answers.

Comment: Turns out I also had my Encoding as MTOM at one end and "non-MTOM" (forgetting the other option) at the other.  With that ironed out, it sprang to life.

Comment: Just want to admit that I've posted nearly the same message over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7238931/wcf-config-files-and-the-famous-string-content-length-quota-8192-error -- because the problem came back and I cannot defeat it...