# WCF config files - and the famous "string content length quota (8192)" error

Tags: wcf, iis, web-config, app-config

Folks,

Thanks for your help with my previous WCF config file issue.  Here's a new one.

My project is a WinForms app client (.NET 4.0) that pulls data from (and saves it to) a WCF services hosted on IIS 7.0.  When I save a small payload, all is well.  When I try to save a payload over 8192 bytes the error is:

> The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the
>   message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter
>   http://tempuri.org/:objEncounterType. The InnerException message was
>   'There was an error deserializing the object of type
>   PsychCoverage.Common.EncounterType. The maximum string content length
>   quota (8192) has been exceeded while reading XML data. This quota may
>   be increased by changing the MaxStringContentLength property on the
>   XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas object used when creating the XML reader.
>   Line 1, position 10809.'.  Please see InnerException for more
>   details

I have confirmed that my `<binding name="">` is the same as my `<endpoint bindingConfiguration="">`.

I've set my `maxReceivedMessageSize` and `maxBufferPoolSize` and  `maxBufferSize` all to 10,000,000 on both my client `app.config` and my `web.config`. I tried making my `<readerQuota>` values very high.

In my web.config I set `<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="10000000" />`

This is from my client `app.config`:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="wcfAdmin_binding"           
             maxReceivedMessageSize="10000000" 
             maxBufferPoolSize="10000000" 
             maxBufferSize="10000000" 
             messageEncoding="Text" 
             sendTimeout="00:05:00" 
             receiveTimeout="00:05:00"
             bypassProxyOnLocal="false" 
             hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
             textEncoding="utf-8" 
             useDefaultWebProxy="true" 
             allowCookies="false"
             >
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="200" maxStringContentLength="10000000" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="10000000" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <security mode="None"></security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <clear/>
  <endpoint address="http://localhost/PsychCoverage/Admin.svc" name="AdminUIClientEndpoint" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wcfAdmin_binding" contract="PsychCoverage.Common.IAdmin">
    <identity>
      <dns value="localhost" />
    </identity>
  </endpoint>
</client>

</system.serviceModel>
```

And this is from my service `web.config`:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="False" ></serviceHostingEnvironment>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="wcfAdmin_binding"  
             maxReceivedMessageSize="10000000" 
             maxBufferPoolSize="10000000" 
             maxBufferSize="10000000" 
             messageEncoding="Text" 
             sendTimeout="00:05:00" 
             receiveTimeout="00:05:00">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="200" 
                    maxStringContentLength="10000000" 
                    maxArrayLength="16384" 
                    maxBytesPerRead="10000000" 
                    maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <security mode="None"></security>
    </binding>
    <binding name="wcfClientWebPortal_binding" 
              maxReceivedMessageSize="10000000" 
              maxBufferPoolSize="10000000" 
              maxBufferSize="10000000" 
              messageEncoding="Text" 
              sendTimeout="00:05:00" 
              receiveTimeout="00:05:00">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="200" 
                    maxStringContentLength="10000000" 
                    maxArrayLength="16384" 
                    maxBytesPerRead="10000000" 
                    maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <security mode="None"></security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="wcfBehavior" name="PsychCoverage.WcfMT.Admin">
    <endpoint address="" 
              binding="basicHttpBinding" 
              bindingConfiguration="wcfAdmin_binding"
              name="AdminEndpoint" 
              bindingName="wcfAdmin_binding" 
              contract="PsychCoverage.Common.IAdmin">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
  </service>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="wcfBehavior" name="PsychCoverage.WcfMT.ClientWebPortal">
    <endpoint address="" 
              binding="basicHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="wcfClientWebPortal_binding"
              name="ClientWebPortalEndpoint" 
              bindingName="wcfClientWebPortal_binding"
              contract="PsychCoverage.Common.IClientWebPortal">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="wcfBehavior">
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
      set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="False" />
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
      set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
      to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="100" maxConcurrentSessions="100" maxConcurrentInstances="100" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, I posted something very like this over at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6853013/wcf-config-file-something-is-plainly-wrong, and at the time, that answer worked.  But I'm still applying that answer, and still can't get through this one...

Comment: You don't seem to have a `<client>` section in your client's `app.config` file - how does that client even connect?? Are you setting up everything in code? Or did you post the wrong file??

Comment: @TomK - why do you have a service endpoint defined in your client's App.config?  I doubt that has anything to do with your problem, just curious.  As for your current issue, are you doing any client and/or service creation in the code where you specify `new BasicHttpBinding()`?  If so, that will give you the default binding settings.

Comment: marc_s and Tim -- thanks!  Yes, I had done a rather silly copy/paste of the app.config.  I've edited the above but the problem persists.  No matter what I do, it thinks my maxStringContentLength=8192.

Comment: Just a thought.  I'm presuming the problems here are on the client side.  But it says the error is happening during this Save() operation, when trying to DEserialize the object.  Is that a problem on the server-side, then?

Comment: And how do I (can I?) set breakpoints in VS on the server side, given that IIS is handling the request?  I'd love to see what the binding and endpoint *think* they're doing when this happens.

Comment: What is the full stack of the exception? That would tell where the error actually happens.

Comment: @TomK - if the error is happening during the save, then the issue is on the service side, not the client side.